# Index Seek vs. Clustered Index Scan - Why is the scan chosen?

Tags: sql-server

The following query uses an index seek on an index on the LastModifiedTime column.

```
SELECT 
      CONVERT(varchar, a.ReadTime, 101) as ReadDate,
      a.SubID,
      a.PlantID,
      a.Unit as UnitID,
      a.SubAssembly
FROM dbo.Accepts a WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE  a.LastModifiedTime BETWEEN '3/3/2010' And '3/4/2010'
AND a.SubAssembly = '400'
```

The query below, which is almost identical to the above query, uses a clustered index scan, instead of the index on LastModifiedTime. Can anyone tell me why? And, more importantly, what I can do to get SQL Server to use the index on the LastModifiedTime column, **without** using an index hint.

```
Declare @LastModifiedTimeEnd dateTime
Declare @LastModifiedTimeStart dateTime

    SELECT 
          CONVERT(varchar, a.ReadTime, 101) as ReadDate,
          a.SubID,
          a.PlantID,
          a.Unit as UnitID,
          a.SubAssembly
    FROM dbo.Accepts a WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE  a.LastModifiedTime BETWEEN @LastModifiedTimeStart And @LastModifiedTimeEnd
    AND a.SubAssembly = '400'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The query below, which is almost identical to the above query, uses a clustered index scan, instead of the index on `LastModifiedTime`. Can anyone tell me why?

The query below does not know the values of the parameters when building the plan and assumes that *in general*, the clustered index scan is better.

> And, more importantly, what I can do to get SQL Server to use the index on the `LastModifiedTime` column, without using an index hint.

```
SELECT 
      CONVERT(varchar, a.ReadTime, 101) as ReadDate,
      a.SubID,
      a.PlantID,
      a.Unit as UnitID,
      a.SubAssembly
FROM dbo.Accepts a WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE  a.LastModifiedTime BETWEEN @LastModifiedTimeStart And @LastModifiedTimeEnd
AND a.SubAssembly = '400'
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@LastModifiedTimeStart = '3/3/2010', @LastModifiedTimeEnd = '3/4/2010'))
```

Alternatively, you can add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, which will create the different execution plan each time the query is run, taking the parameter values into the account (*parameter sniffing*).

This, however, does not guarantee that the index will be used.

Comment: I'm confused as to why the query planner would assume the clustered index is better. Regardless of what the parameters are, it is still matching against a specific column which has an index created for it. What is the point of that index if it's only used with fixed parameters?

Comment: @Kent: using a secondary index to retrieve a range of values requires joining the index back to the table. When the range is large, the join overhead outweighs the sorting overhead.

Comment: I see - thanks. Guess I kind of assumed parameter sniffing would be default behavior. Presumably using `>= @LastModifiedTimeStart AND <= LastModifiedTimeEnd` would also preclude the use of the non-clustered index without specifying `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`.

Comment: @Kent: `BETWEEN` is just a syntax sugar for the expression you provided. This expression is parsed and optimized in the very same way as `BETWEEN` is.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a plan guide with [sp_create_plan_guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179880.aspx). See [Optimizing Queries in Deployed Applications by Using Plan Guides](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187032.aspx). A plan guide will help the optimizer into deciding whether to use the index range seek or the clustered scan.